# Can you add characters from a string to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, char

I'm wondering if it's possible to take a string e.g. `str(input())` and split it into individual `char`s, then add them to a `list`. I'm trying to make a simple script (something similar to a hangman game) and at the beginning I wrote this:

```
x=input('Choose word: ').lower()
letters=[]
letters.append(list(x))
print(letters)
```

but this code appends the whole `list` to a `list` and not individual `char`s

Edit: this outputs `[['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']]` meaning that the whole list got appended as one item, but I want this to output `['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']`, how do I make it append individual chars and not the whole list

Comment: Please give a concrete example of your expected output

Comment: this outputs ```[['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']]``` meaning that the whole list got appended as one item, but i want this to output ```['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extend instead of append function.

```
#Extend
x=input('Choose word: ').lower()
letters=[]
letters.extend(list(x))
print(letters)

# ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

And to remove a character from a list while retaining position as blank after removing, use replace while within a list:

```
y=input("Choose a letter to remove: ").lower()
removed=[s.replace(y,'') for s in letters]
print(removed)

#['p', '', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

I hope this help, unless its different from what you want. Then let me know. Otherwise, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

You are simply wrapping the char list in another list.

Try this one-liner instead:

```
print(list(x))
```

If you want to remove a character:

```
letters = list(x)
letters.remove('o')
print(letters)
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to remove a ```char``` from this? Something like ```list.remove()```?

Comment: @Kacper You didn't mention removing a character on your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an empty list and then populate it with individual letters. Simply apply the `list()` function directly for the user input to create it:

```
letters = list(input('Choose word: ').lower())
print(letters)
```

For adding letters from the other user input, use the same approach with the `.extend()` method:

```
letters.extend(input('Choose word: ').lower())        # No need to use list() here
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner:

```
x = input().lower().split()
print(x)
```

here we are taking the input and then we are converting to lowercase and then using the split function which will split the string on white spaces you can split the string on whatever string you feel like just give the string you want to split on as the argument in the split function for example:

```
x = input().lower().split(',')
print(x)
```

this will split on the ',' so you can give the input in csv format

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `+` operator (preferably in the form of an augmented assignment statement, i.e. `+=`, for extending the list to an iterable.

No need to use the `list()` function here, because the string is iterable:

```
letters = []
letters += input('Choose word: ').lower()
print(letters)
```

Answer (score -1):

> this outputs `[['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']]` meaning that the whole
> list got appended as one item, but i want this to output `['o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't']`

Based on you comment, you can use:

```
x = [*input('Choose word: ').lower()]
print(x)
# ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/b788085ab6)